# Cuál es el significado de -1 en max_input_time

Tags: php, wordpress

Buenas,

¿Cuál es el significado de -1 en `max_input_time =-1`?

Gracias

Comment: Cómo no sabemos que es `max_input_time` ni en que contexto lo estás usando, significa que es: _el número **uno** entero menor que cero_. Te recomiendo que leas esta guía: _[ask]_ y en tus preguntas, de ser posible agrega un __[mcve]__.

Comment: Gracias. Me lo ha resuelto Francisco Romero. El contexto en el que lo preguntaba es el de los requisitos mínimos de configuración de PHP para realizar una acción de un plugin de Wordpress.

Answer (score 3):

Según la **[documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time)**:

> **max_input_time integer**
>   Establece el tiempo máximo en segundos que se permite a un script analizar datos de entrada, como POST y GET. La medición comienza en el momento en que PHP es invocado en el servidor y finaliza cuando la ejecución comienza.

El -1 refleja que no tiene tiempo máximo en segundos, es decir, que el tiempo que se le permite a un script analizar datos de entrada es infinito.